# JWT UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found (GET request with cookie)

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt

I have a strange problem, or maybe I don't understand how JWT works in Express context.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var expressJWT = require('express-jwt');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var unless = require('express-unless');


app.set('secret', 'some secret');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use("/", expressJWT({secret:app.get('secret')})
  .unless({
    path:[
      '/',
      '/foo',
      '/login'
    ]}
  ));


  // my custom route middleware to verify a token
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("------------------------------------");
  console.log("route middleware to verify a token");
  console.log("");
  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.access_token || req.query.access_token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.cookies.access_token;
  console.log("req.cookies.access_token:", req.cookies.access_token);
  console.log("token:", token);
  // decode token
  if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('secret'), function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("jwt.verify ERROR")
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.', err:err });
      } else {
        console.log("jwt.verify OK")
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided.'
    });

  }
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.send('Hello World!. /foo is open, /bar is protected. Login at /login')
})

app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {

  res.send('Foo')
})

app.get('/bar', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Foo')
})

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  var username = 'mock_username';
  var myToken = jwt.sign({username:username}, app.get('secret'));
  res.cookie('access_token', myToken).send("logged in, check cookie");
})


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

I'm setting up a JWT token and saving it to cookie in the /login route.
This works and the token is set if I check cookie in the browser (dev tools in Chrome).

- I visit the / or */foo* route (unprotected as specified with unless), and browser displays correct result, but the console still throws the *UnauthorizedError*. Why is the error showing in the console if I explicitly marked this as unprotected route with "unless"?
- I visit */bar* route (protected), my middleware is not being called, I get the *UnauthorizedError* both in console and the browser. How do I make sure the middleware does get triggered here, and how do I provide the access to this route if the token is indeed found and verified in my middleware?

Comment: because you have not attached `unless` with other middleware.

Comment: Which ones, all of them? This is an answer to first question out of two. Please put it in the form of an answer so I can upvote and give you points :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I visit the / or /foo route (unprotected as specified with unless), and browser displays correct result, but the console still throws the UnauthorizedError. Why is the error showing in the console if I explicitly marked this as unprotected route with "unless"?

By specifiying `unless`, you made the `/` and `/foo` route unprotected from `app.use("/", expressJWT(...)` only, not from subsequent `middlewares`. The request will pass to your custom middlware too.

> I visit /bar route (protected), my middleware is not being called, I get the UnauthorizedError both in console and the browser. How do I make sure the middleware does get triggered here, and how do I provide the access to this route if the token is indeed found and verified in my middleware?

Because, the application got crashed at `app.use("/", expressJWT(...))`,  when it could not find `authorization token`. Hence, it could not reach to your custom middleware.

**Possible solution : 1**

Since `JWT` token is stored in `cookie` in your case, you can set `getToken` method to get the token and let `express-jwt` to verify it, and remove your custom middleware altogether.

e.g.

```
app.use("/", expressJWT({
  secret : app.get('secret'),
  getToken: function fromCookie (req) {
    var token = req.cookies.access_token || req.body.access_token || req.query.access_token || req.headers['x-access-token'] ;
    if (token) {
      return token;
    } 
    return null;
  }
}).unless({
    path:[
      '/',
      '/foo',
      '/login'
    ]}
));
```

and handle the error

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    return res.status(403).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'No token provided.'
    });
  }
});
```

**Possible Solution : 2**

You can do the custom `jwt` verification by implementing your custom middleware (that you have already done). Then there is no need of the following middleware at all.

Remove the following line.

```
app.use("/", expressJWT({secret:app.get('secret')}).unless(...)
```

And for protecting and unprotecting the routes, put `unprotected` routes before the the custom middleware and `protected` route after custom middleware (naive way).

Hope it helps you.